# elasticsearch - filebeat - How to define multiline in filebeat.inputs with conditions?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filebeat, elk

in our cluster some apps are sending logs as multiline, and the problem is that the log structure is different from app to app.

How can we set up an 'if' condition that will include the

```
    multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
    multiline.negate: true
    multiline.match: after
```

In it?

Our code:

filebeatConfig:
filebeat.yml: |

```yaml
      filebeat.inputs:
      - type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*.log
        processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            host: ${NODE_NAME}
            matchers:
            - logs_path:
                logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
        - drop_event:
            when:
              contains:
                container.image.name: "kibana"
              

      output.logstash:
        hosts: ["logstash-listener:5044"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [auto-discovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html) (either Docker or Kubernetes) with [template conditions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/defining-processors.html#conditions).

You will probably have at least two templates, one for capturing your containers that emit multiline messages and another for other containers.

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      templates:
        - condition:               <--- your multiline condition goes here
            contains:
              kubernetes.namespace: xyz-namespace
          config:
            - type: container
              paths:
                - /var/lib/docker/containers/${data.docker.container.id}/*.log
              multiline:
                pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
                negate: true
                match: after
              processors:
                - add_kubernetes_metadata:
                  host: ${NODE_NAME}
                  matchers:
                  - logs_path:
                     logs_path: "/var/log/containers/"
                - drop_event:
                    when:
                      contains:
                        container.image.name: "kibana"
```